# How to match a `universe#Type` via quasiquotes or deconstructors?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

I have a type `resultType` of `Context.this.type#c#universe#Type`. I need to match it against `Unit` type. I tried

```
resultType match {
  case q"Unit" => ...
}
```

but I suppose that `Unit` is just a string literal here that obviously do not match. How to match types via quasiqotes?

And I also tried

```
resultType match {
  case TypeRef(ThisType(_), Symbol("scala.Unit"), _) => ...
}
```

but have an error:

```
[error]  pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
[error]  found   : Symbol
[error]  required: Context.this.c.universe.SymbolContextApi
```

How to match a type in that way?

Comment: Try `case tq"Unit" => ...`. See [documentation](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/quasiquotes.html).

Comment: @senia it works. Do you wish to post an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: @senia Sorry, my mistake. Eventually this does not match. Any ideas?

Comment: Quasiquotes only work with subtypes of `Tree`. `Type` is not a `Tree`, it's a separate concept of the reflection api and that's why you need to match on them through `TypeRef` and friends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primary reason why quasiquotes don't work in this case is the fact that you don't match on a `Tree` but rather a `Type`. These two are separate concepts of the reflection API that are not quite the same.

A simple way to check if type is the same as the one you expect is to use `typeOf` and type equality operator `=:=`:

```
case tpe if tpe =:= typeOf[Unit] =>
```

Of course this is not the only way. One can also match through `TypeRef` and check for equality of symbols inside of it as shown in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

A variation on your answer, debatable if it is any better:

```
case TypeRef(_, sym, _) if sum == typeOf[Unit].typeSymbol => ...
```

Comment: There is a silgtly better way. Consider: https://github.com/sirthias/parboiled2/blob/695ee6603359cfcb97734edf6dd1d27383c48727/parboiled-core/src/main/scala/org/parboiled2/support/OpTreeContext.scala#L595-L596. You're welcome to fix your answer, and I mark it as a best one.

Comment: If I follow, that would mean: `case TypeRef(_, sym, _) if sym == c.mirror.staticClass("scala.Unit") => ...`. This seems like a step backwards to me.

Comment: Please, explain why your is better?

Comment: This is getting into the weeds but I prefer not having a hard-coded string `"scala.Unit"` in the code, and `typeOf[Unit].typeSymbol` is fairly self-documenting that it is producing a TypeSymbol for Unit, whereas `c.mirror.staticClass("scala.Unit")` makes me hunt for the documentation of staticClass to understand what is happening.

Comment: @eugene-burmako, @denys-shabalin, do you know if `typeOf[Unit]` has some drawbacks?

Comment: `case tpe if tpe =:= typeOf[Unit] =>` is as good solution as any.

Comment: Confirming this works for me. @DenysShabalin do you want to submit it as an answer?

Answer (score -1):

Alas, I found nothing smarter than this:

```
case TypeRef(_, sym, _) if sym.fullName == "scala.Unit" => ...
```